# Listview in javafx

Tags: javafx

I made simple listview in javafx. If I press a key, loaded the data from database to list from like query. Now I want to select the 1st item in list view at key released. I try to do this from listview.getselectionmodel ().selectfirst () method. It select the 1st item as temporary. If I want to move up or down on the list, I happen to give a mouse click to list and then I can move up or down from arrow keys. But I don't want this manner. I want, if I give key released,the data loaded and that moment i can up or down on listview from arrow keys. What should I do? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

To move focus to your `ListView`, call `requestFocus()`.

```
// in your handler
listView.getItems().addAll(Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3"));
listView.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
Platform.runLater(listView::requestFocus);
```

Focused `ListView` will accepts key operations immediately.

Comment: Thanks monolith52 .i will try it.